# Unit testing controller action with onactionexecuting fired

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I want to do a unit test on a controller's action, and the OnActionExecuting filter must run before the action can execute correctly.

I use many action filters so i don't want to manually execute them each time I do a test.

If I call the controller action method directly like below, I can get the result but the filters are not executed.

```
ViewResult vr = myController.MyAction("hello world") as ViewResult;
Assert.AreEqual("View1", vr.ViewName);
```

I found how to get the action filters executed when calling an action like this:

```
var routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values["controller"] = "MyController";
routeData.Values["action"] = "MyAction";

var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), routeData);
(myController as IController).Execute(rc);
```

But then I can't find the way to get the action result, is it possible to fire the action filters AND get the action result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missing few points here.

You generally want to **verify the behavior in isolation** if you are talking about the Unit testing.

I would personally test the action filters separately and test your controller action method separately. If you want to make sure your Controller's Action method uses a certain Filter attribute, that's a separate Unit Test. For that you can use something like [this](http://blog.rajsoftware.com/post/2012/12/04/Simple-test-helper-MVC-Action-has-decorated-with-a-certain-attribute.aspx).

The benefit of doing this way is that you can find issues in isolation without having to worry about other dependencies. You get the maximum benefit of automating your Unit tests this way.

Comment: Hmm... you are probably right, but i just thought it was easier to let the OnActionExecuting do its job of initializing some variables, etc. before my action is executed, instead of all initializing manually in the test method.

Comment: Thanks, it might be easier, but you want to decouple your action filter/onActionExecuting from you unit testing aspect of your Controller. Those variables, you can stub out accordingly. They provide canned answers to you SUT ( your Controller's Action method) You need that decoupled isolation, your test would less complicated, precise, and as I mentioned in my answer you get the maximum benefit out of your unit test.

Comment: I applied the method described in your blog to test if an action is decorated with an attribute, but i get tne following compilation error: "System.Array has no definition for Any"
at this line 
`return methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(a => a is TAttribute);`
Any idea ?

Comment: oups, just needed the using System.Linq instruction sorry, newbie error ;)